# Does pollution affect the color of the sky?

Tags: optics, scattering, atmospheric-science

We know that the sky is blue due to Rayleigh Scattering.  We know that Rayleigh Scattering is dependent on the size of the particles in the atmosphere.  We know that pollution is made up of particles, and these particles can interact with and destroy ozone particles in the air.

If the particles in the atmosphere are being destroyed, and new ones, presumably with a different size, are being added, does this change the color of the sky? (Assume the sun is directly overhead and there are no clouds.)

Comment: Have a look at light scattering in Wikipedia. In short the answer is yes. Think of Mars photos taken by the various rover missions.

Comment: Related Q&As: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/why-would-mars-sky-appear-blue-at-dawn-and-dusk-but-red-during-the-middle-of-t    and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24804/do-the-gases-in-the-earths-atmosphere-affect-the-color-of-a-lunar-eclipse

Answer (score -1):

Just an observation - It certainly changed the sky color in North America to strange for months in 1991 when the Kuwait oil wells were burning, or Mt Pinatubo eruption depending on your politics.

Comment: I don't think politics would change the reasons for the sky changing colours.

Comment: My point was that the sky color was changed by a pollution factor, democrats said it was the burning oil wells, republicans said it was Mt Pinatubo suggesting it wasn't the fault of their war, but a natural disaster instead...which was it?  I don't know.

Answer (score -3):

Yes it does. Apparently I need more words even though they do not add anything useful to my answer, how strange.

Comment: Such short answers should maybe become a comment.

Comment: No, answers should be answers, because comments don't live eternally. However, the answer could be expanded to add some information about the effect, size of the effect, etc.

Comment: It's completely inappropriate and illogical to add bland sentences to cheat the character limit. The intention is to prevent answers like this which simply say 'yes' and help practically nobody.

Comment: @Chair useless questions get useless answers. The answer above answers the question in full.